# Text File Formatting a Dictionary-like Line to Individual Lines

Tags: unix, text, awk, sed, formatting

I have a text file that is tab separated with at least two columns in each line. The first column is an unique ID and every column after is an identifier of a fasta sequence (DNA Sequence Identifier). My question is how to reshape this structure to a two column matrix.

This means I want to go from this data format:

```
1040713 91
969805  47
862949  502 485
798097  671 593
939058  575
721526  400 523 76  610
```

To this data format:

```
1040713 91
969805  47
862949  502 
862949  485
798097  671 
798097  593
939058  575
721526  400
721526  523
721526  76
721526  610
```

I am trying to use awk -F '\t' '{print $3}' | to a sed with a new line character and the first column. However, I am unsure how to access the first column after the pipe. Any suggestions to achieve my desired formatting would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1 "\t" $i}'
```

Comment: This is perfect. AWK is my hero!!